# Pegar o valor de uma input pelo name

Tags: php, html

Olá,

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
function capturar($string, $start, $end) {
    $str = explode($start, $string);
    $str = explode($end, $str[1]);
    return $str[0];
}
```

Eu uso ela com o cURL, para pegar o valor de um input.

Exemplo de uso:

```
$pagina = curl("http://example.com");
$texto = capturar($pagina, 'name="texto"', '"');
echo $texto;
```

Aí no caso, o PHP iria retornar o valor do input ou qualquer tag que tenha o `name` de `texto`, até aí tudo bem, mas a página que o cURL acessa tem o seguinte input:

```
<input value="João Lima" name="texto" id="texto"/>
```

Como eu iria pegar o valor do input nesta ordem?

Obrigado desde já.

---

Atual código que eu estou usando:

```
<?php
function curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd().'/test.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd().'/test.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
$array = [];
preg_match('/value="([^"]+)"/e', curl('http://example.com'), $array);
var_dump($array);
echo '<br><br><br><br>'.curl('http://example.com');
```

Nesta página tem outros inputs, mas tem um input com o `value` de `11.5, 12, 12.5`.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o ideal é usar o próprio [XPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php), nativo do PHP.

---

Neste caso utiliza o `//input[@name="texto"]` que para obter o `input` que contem o atributo de `name` de `texto`.

Dessa forma ficaria como:

```
$html = curl("http://example.com");

$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$XPath = new DomXPath($DOM);

// Procura pelo elemento:
$inputs = $XPath->query('//input[@name="texto"]');

// Para cada //input[@name="texto"] (já que pode haver mais de um) e exibe o `value`.
foreach($inputs as $_ => $input){
    echo $input->getAttribute('value');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se for um único input, isso aqui deve resolver:

```
$conteudo = '<input value="João Lima" name="texto" id="texto"/>';
$array = [];
preg_match('/value="([^"]+)"/e',$conteudo,$array);
var_dump($array);
```

Este é apenas um exemplo, deverá ser adaptado. O `$conteudo` deverá ser o retorno da tua requisição feita com CURL.

Comment: E quando o `value` conter números? Coloquei um input com o `value` de `11.5, 12, 12.5` e não retornou o `value` na array.

Comment: Tem certeza, pois testei com esses valores e funcionou. Ta fazendo dessa forma: value="11.5" ?

Comment: Sim, eu testei com esses valores só na string, depois eu fui testar com o cURL, mas ele não retorna.